# C#: Autogenerating DDL and ORM classes from XML schema (XSD) file

Tags: c#, xslt, orm, xsd, xsd.exe

I have a rather large XSD file available [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?kcqjtqithjtcgc5).

I want to generate the following from the file:

1. Generate DDL (for PostgreSQL), the DDL should contain initial values where appropriate, as specified by 'permitted' values in the XSD
2. Generate an ORM that will allow me to perform CRUD operations on the records in the database created in step 1

Can anyone suggest a tool or series of tools/technologies to achieve this?

In case I have to roll my own solution, can someone suggest a good tutorial for XSLT (preferably a cookbook - since I already know some XML/XPath).

Incidentally, I tried xsd.exe on Windows - it failed and printed an error message suggesting that there was a circular reference in the XSD file. I then tried xsd.exe on mono, that worked - but the file created had some invalid statements. I am guessing (perhaps incorrectly) that xsd.exe is NOT the way to achieve these twin goals - if I am wrong, let me know.

Also, I took at [Ann Lewkowicz's XSLT transform file](http://www.annlewkowicz.com/2008/01/create-ddl-from-xsd-file-part-ii.html) to generate a DDL from an XSD file - BUT that appeared to have got stuck in an infinite loop - and also complained about 'infinite recursion'

So I need help with the following:

- First of all, can anyone test/check if the [XSD file](http://www.mediafire.com/?kcqjtqithjtcgc5) is indeed **screwed up**? - and if it is, how to fix it?
- How do I go about generating a DDL and ORM from the XSD file?

Comment: Regarding generating DDL/ORM, have you looked at T4? I personally think that T4 is much more suited for these tasks than XSLT (http://www.olegsych.com/2007/12/text-template-transformation-toolkit/).

Comment: The XSD is screwed. Get this error when I try to open it in VS: This schema is an invalid XSD Schema and has the following error(s): The 'http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace:lang' attribute is not declared.

Comment: @hugh jadick: Thanks for the confirmation. I have fixed the problem (not uploaded fixed file yet though) - so the only remaining problem is how to generate an ORM and DDL from the XSD. I have managed to open the fixed XSD file in Visual Studio (looks really nice!). Surely there must be a way to generate DDL and ORM from Visual Studio?

Comment: I'm not an expert on ORM but have you looked at Entity Framework which is Microsofts ORM offering?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would have written the generator myself. There may be good generators out there, but I haven't seen any. All I've tried using (though I never used an XSD as the starting point) generate terrible code, and worse, are rather impossible to customize to handle every quirk that inevitably turns up.

Doing so is a lot less work than people seem to imagine, and gives many benefits, not least that you'll actually have total control over exactly what is generated. And you could even (and quite easily) take it to the next level and generate the stuff at run-time. The latter is hardly meaningful if the schema is final, but can be a huge time-saver if it's constantly evolving.

I'm quite sure this isn't the answer you were hoping for, and I'd be interested too if anyone knows of good tools for the job.